# Form Post HTTPS

Tags: html, forms, security, https

I'm trying to submit a form back to my server using POST and the target is at the same domain (which is HTTPS) however when I submit I get a Mixed Content error. Does the form post not follow the same protocol as the hosting page? If so what is the best way to fix it without always specifying the full url (I use sub domains for different companies)

Comment: Please consider providing your (broken) code. It's hard, if not impossible, to help without any idea of the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the form post not follow the same protocol as the hosting page?

It does if a relative URL is specified.

e.g. path relative

```
action="/form/foo"
```

or protocol relative

```
action="//example.com/form/foo"
```

It appears you have something on your action page, or the page that it redirects to loading over plain HTTP. Use developer tools to hunt out this reference.